# Where can I add list of external URL for WP ADD link tool?

Tags: urls, import

I Want to import my ecommerce product links and categories here for WP. That would make linking easier by searching products and categories inside WP own search..

I have them all in CSV, but I have no idea where to import them? What table it uses? WP_post, WP_postmeta, ... And correct format. Can anyone help?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

if you install Betheme
there is a add "shop slider" which lets you to list your products according you catagories.
you dont need CVS file, or final link etc, allready you may change your final links later thus this way may give you extra job effort.
however if you use betheme, you can just add any category you wish.

Comment: Thanks. Please note that im using External ecommerce solution, not WP. WP is jut for Blog.